# btrfs (v0.20-rc1) Check tree block failed

Tags: linux, btrfs

I am trying to recover a btrfs filesystem and have hit a dead end

`btrfs check --repair --init-csum-tree --init-extent-tree /dev/mapper/VG_00-LV_opt`

```
enabling repair mode
Creating a new CRC tree`
Check tree block failed, want=20975616, have=0
Check tree block failed, want=20975616, have=0
Check tree block failed, want=20975616, have=0
Check tree block failed, want=20975616, have=0
Check tree block failed, want=20975616, have=0
read block failed check_tree_block
Couldn't read chunk root
```

Comment: can you add some history on what you did to it so it needs recovery? that might help understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the latest tools for btrfs

```
git clone https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs.git
```

Then ran:

```
btrfs rescue chunk-recover /dev/mapper/VG_00-LV_opt
```

That fixed it, the version of the tools on the server did not have the rescue option.